# Comparing sigma-algebras generated by a random variable and its induced posterior

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, polish-spaces

Consider two random variables $\tilde x$ and $\tilde y$ taking values in Polish spaces $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Let the (prior) distribution of $\tilde x$ be $\nu$ and the distribution of $\tilde y$ conditional on $\tilde x=x$ is $P_x$. So $\tilde y$ is characterized by the collection $\{({Y},{\cal B}(Y),P_x)\}_{x\in X}$.

Given $y$, then one can obtain $\mu_y$, the distribution of $\tilde x$ conditional on $y$. Then we can have another random element $\mu_{\tilde y}$ taking values in the space of distributions on $X$.

I am interested to know if $\sigma(\mu_{\tilde y}) \subset \sigma (\tilde y)$? Intuitively, it seems to be true as the information generated, or every event determined, by $\mu_{\tilde y}$  is an event that's determined by $\tilde y$. While it seems to be true with $X$ and $Y$ being finite, for general Polish spaces, I cannot approve or disapprove it. Any hint of the proof or counterexample (if it is not true in general?) Thank you!

Comment: To check this you have to have a sigma algebra defined on the space of probability measures on $X$. You can use the Borel sigma algebra if you use a topology on this space, but Im not sure what the most popular choice is. Then you have to do the usual check for sigma algebra containment, which is to check that the generators of one sigma algebra are contained in the other. You will likely need to use the fact that $\mu$ can be chosen so that $\mu_y(A)$ is a measurable function of $y$ for all Borel sets $A$.

Comment: Thank you, Mason. Sorry I should have specified that Borel sigma algebras would be used. And indeed, I had trouble to show the measurability of $\mu_y$ (viewed as a disintegration) in $y$. Any  references or other suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: @Y Ava The existence of the regular conditional probability kernel $\mu(y, A)$ is a non-trivial result that uses the assumption that X and Y are Polish spaces. I believe Klenke's Probability theory book has a proof of its existence.

Comment: @Mason Thanks a lot!!!